# Embedding a link in an email using MailApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project to embed a link (that will activate a function in my script when clicked) into an E-mail using JavaScript in the Google Sheet script editor. I'm not sure if my code is just wrong or if Google just doesn't allow links. Here is my code:

```
function doStuff(){
  var email = "email@emai.com"
  var subject = "hi"
  var message = "lets hope this works"

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message)
}

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,<a href="javascript:doStuff" onclick="doStuff();">Run JavaScript Code</a>);
```

Comment: in every email client javascript isnt allowed. Thats basics. I'm working In big company where we do newsletter mailings. So html tables and css for responsive (few clients allow) nothing more, maybe gif or svg generated graphics with custom font.

Comment: Is there a way to get my link into that email than... I am using the link to than update my google sheet information. Some project management stuff so that if a project is approved they click the link on the bottom of the email saying approved and it updates my sheet with the approval.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a syntax error. I do not know what is MailApp but I doubt is gonna work as it is, you should add quotes to handle as a string like this:

```
 MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,"<a href='javascript:doStuff' onclick='doStuff();'>Run JavaScript Code</a>");
```

Anyway I agree with @Szymon Dziewoński, it is very unlikely that an email client interprets javascript. Actually the same email provider could strip it from the body of the email. Take a look to this [guide](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/), you will notice that they do not mention javascript at all. Only HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that syntax error. Also, than is there a way to put html code into my existing java script code so that I can get a link into my emails that are being sent out. I just cant think of a way and my research has not been helpful.